# Adding text on each line of the document with php

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I want to add exact same text on each line of the file but can't make it. The reason is because I have 1k+ rows and doing this manually will be pain. What I have so far is this:

```
$file_data = "my string \n";
$file_data .= file_get_contents('numbers.txt');
file_put_contents('numbers.txt', $file_data);
```

This put at the very first line of the text file the string and that's it. How to put on each line?

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya thank's. I don't know how I've missed this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From duplicated thread

```
$lines = file('numbers.txt'); 
$new = '';

if (is_array($lines)) {
    foreach($lines as $line) { 
        $new .= "my string " . $line;
    } 
}

file_put_contents('numbers.txt', $new);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create a new file and write the string before every line:

```
<?php
$string = "my string \n";
$fh = fopen('numbers.txt', 'r');
$fh2 = fopen('new-numbers.txt', 'w');

if ($fh && $fh2) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($fh, 4096)) !== false) {
        $buffer = $string . $buffer;
        fwrite($fh2, $buffer);
    }

    if (!feof($fh)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($fh);
    fclose($fh2);
}
```